# Bug in GCE Developer Console 'equivalent command line'

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

When attempting to create an instance in a project that includes local SSDs, I am given the following (redacted) command line equivalent:

```
gcloud compute --project "PROJECTS" instances create "INSTANCE" --zone "us-central1-f" \ 
--machine-type "n1-standard-2" --network "default" --maintenance-policy "MIGRATE" \
--scopes [...] --tags "http-server" --local-ssd-count "2" \
--image "ubuntu-1404-trusty-v20150316" --boot-disk-type "pd-standard" \
--boot-disk-device-name "INSTANCEDEVICE"
```

This fails with:

`ERROR: (gcloud) unrecognized arguments: --local-ssd-count 2`

Indeed, I find no mention of `--local-ssd-count` in the current docs: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create

Changing this to `--local-ssd --local-ssd` works, as then the default are used.

This is using `Google Cloud SDK 0.9.54`, the most recent after `gcloud components update`.

Comment: Is this a question or are you just letting the community know?  This might be better placed in meta or as a non-question article.

Comment: I agree, I can make this a non-question/meta article.

It's basically a bug report, but I don't have Silver or higher GCE support.

Comment: I see now the CLI is kept in Github - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud - the various gcloud libraries (python, ruby) all show up first.

I'll open an issue there. I suppose this "question" could be removed since I don't see it having any historical value once the docs/CLI are fixed.

Comment: Actually, I take it back. Neither that gcloud link nor gcloud-python seem to have the code in question, `lib/googlecloudsdk/compute/lib/instance_utils.py`, which is where I'd like to report the issue.

Googling finds the SDK hosted on Google Code - https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/ - but when I clone the repo it's empty. And the 'Issues' tab Google Group were last used almost a year ago.

Is the SDK code not kept in Git? I can only find tarballs here - https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

Answer (score 0):

If you've found a bug for GCE or have a feature you'd like to propose/request, the best way to report it is to use the 'Public Issue Tracker' that Google has made available.

[Visit this Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/list) to report your feedback/bug/feature request. It **does not** require any support package at all.

I highly encourage you to do so as they have staff actively monitoring and working on those reports (Please note that it's different than what they seem to do on StackOverflow as the tracker is for bugs and feature requests, while SO is for questions). It is likely the best way to get your feedback to their engineers. But we do know that they have staff answering questions on Stack Overflow as well. Questions go here, bug reports go to the tracker as far as I understand.